# Using javascript_pack_tag in rails causes EOFError

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, npm

It looks like files in public/packs/js are not able to load.

These are the javascript tags in the view:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
= javascript_pack_tag 'application'
```

The error in the browser console:

```
net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

This is the error from the rails logs:

```
2020-05-27 11:04:05 -0400: Rack app error handling request { GET /packs/js/application-94e1ca1d6a639b3ce542.js }
#<EOFError: end of file reached>
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:225:in `rbuf_fill'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:191:in `readuntil'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:201:in `readline'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/net_http_hacked.rb:53:in `begin_request_hacked'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/http_streaming_response.rb:60:in `response'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/http_streaming_response.rb:29:in `headers'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:120:in `perform_request'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:27:in `perform_request'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/server.rb:682:in `handle_request'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
/Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
2020-05-27 11:04:05 -0400: Rack app error handling request { GET /packs/js/application-94e1ca1d6a639b3ce542.js }
```

I have reinstalled all gems, node and webpacker, but the issue remains. I read somewhere that rbuf_fill might be expecting https, but I'm not sure where to check that or what changes to make. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's with the Javascript file itself?  End of file issue with application.js.  Is your file being ended early?

Comment: I have removed everything from application.js, compiled the assets again and restarted the server. The issue persists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. I had another rails application running in Docker. Somehow the issue is resolved after stopping the container.

Comment: thanks for sharing your answer! Worked for me too, after turning off a completely different application which was running in a docker-compose setup...

Comment: This solved my issue, huge thank you! I had a `bin/webpack-dev-server`
 running port 3035 and one of the app in docker was also using it.